# Confusion in Solving problems through algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I always get stuck in some situations where i get wrong results, when answers are different. I have two questions

When transposing terms from one side to another, what should I keep in mind? (I sometimes get results in negatives, while answers are in positive)

How do you cancel $3x+6$ in this equation?
$$3x+6-\dfrac{3x+6}{3}=38$$

My friend says $3x+6$ will cancel out each other, but he didn't tell me how, thanks in advance

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Do you mean $$3x+6-\frac{3x+6}{3}=38$$?

Comment: That's $$(3x+6)\left(1-\dfrac13\right)=38$$

Answer (score 1):

DON'T think of "transposing terms from one side to another"!

You are always adding or subtracting or multiplying or dividing.  And you must always do the same thing to both sides.

In the example $3x+ 6- \frac{3x+ 6}{3}= 38$, I would recognize that $\frac{3x+ 6}{3}= \frac{3(x+ 2)}{3}= x+ 2$.  Since that did not involve adding or subtracting or multiplying or dividing the left side by anything new (I would say it is completely "internal" to the left side) I do nothing to the right side: $3x+ 6+ x+ 2= 38$.  Then recognize that 3x+ x= 4x and 6+ 2= 8.  Again, that is "internal" to the left side so nothing is done on the right: $4x+ 8= 38$.

I want to reduce that to "x= something" so I need to get "x" alone on the left side.  It is not alone now because it is multiplied by 4 and then 8 is added to it.  To get x alone, I need to "undo" that- I need to do the opposite.  The opposite of "multiply by 4" is "divide by 4" and the opposite of "add 8" is "subtract 8". And I need to do those in the opposite order!  To go from "4x+ 8" to "x" I need to subtract 8 and divide by 4, in that order.

Subtracting 8 is NOT "internal" to the left side so I need to do it to both sides: 4x+ 8- 8= 38- 8 or 4x= 30 (I did **not** say "transfer 8 to the other side", I said "subtract 8 from both sides").  To go from "4x" to "x" I need to divide both sides by 4: 4x/4= 38/4 so x= 38/4.  That can be reduced to x= 17/2 or x= 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

$3x+6$does not cancel out.

First multiply both sides by $3$ to get $$ 3(3x+6)-(3x+6)=114$$

$$2(3x+6)=114$$

$$3x+6=57$$

$$3x=51$$

$$x=17$$